# Remark 4.31 in Baby Rudin: How to verify these points?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $a$ and $b$ be two real numbers such that $a < b$, let $E$ be any countable subset of the open interval $(a,b)$, and let the elements of $E$ be arranged in a sequence 
$$x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots.$$
Now let $\{c_n\}$ be any sequence of positive real numbers such that the series $\sum c_n$ converges.

Now define the function $f \colon (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows: 
$$f(x) \colon= \sum_{x_n < x} c_n \ \ \ \ \text{ for all } x \in (a,b).$$

Then Rudin states that
(a) the function $f$ is monotonically increasing on $(a,b)$; if $a < x < y < b$, then $$f(y) = \sum_{x_n < y} c_n  \geq \sum_{x_n < x} c_n = f(x)$$ because if any $c_n < x$, then that particular $c_n$ is obviously less than $y$ also. 
(b) $f$ is discontinuous at every point of $E$; in fact, 
$$ f(x_n + ) - f(x_n - ) = c_n.$$ How does this hold? How to show this rigorously using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ approach?
(c) $f$ is continuous at every other point of $(a,b)$. How to show this using the rigorous approach?

Moreover, $f(x-) = f(x) = f(x+)$ at all points of $(a,b)$.

Comment: when you say $x_n<x$ you mean the sum is over the n such that $x_n<x$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry yes, that's exactly what's meant by this sum.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott could you please have a look at this question and duly answer it? Your answers are really wonderful!!

Comment: As the resident simplicity-worshipper, I've attempted to make my answer _simpler_ than the others. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy ... whereas I have gone for one of my Confuse-a-Cat specials.

Comment: @DanielFischer can you please take time answering my question in a fully rigorous manner?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott I'm eagerly awaiting your answer.

Comment: You should accept one of these answer coz they are helpful...if u don't accept good answer means you are literally spoiling others time

Answer (score 11):

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$One nice way to investigate the question rigorously is to consider the "unit step function"
$$
H(x) = \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{if $x \leq 0$,} \\
  1 & \text{if $x > 0$.}
\end{cases}
$$
The function $H$ is obviously non-decreasing and continuous everywhere except $0$.

For each positive integer $n$, the function $f_{n}(x) = c_{n} H(x - x_{n})$ is the "step of height $c_{n}$ at $x_{n}$"; again, this function is obviously non-decreasing and has a "jump" of size $c_{n}$ at $x_{n}$.

The interesting observation is that
$$
f(x) = \sum_{x_{n} < x} f_{n}(x).
$$
It follows at once that $f$ is non-decreasing.

Parts (b) and (c) follow almost immediately from the (easy) fact that the preceding series "converges uniformly" to $f$. However, Rudin doesn't discuss uniform limits until Chapter 7 (if memory serves), so we'll have to establish a tool from the definitions.

**Lemma**: If $x \not\in E$, i.e., if $x \neq x_{n}$ for all $n$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$.

*Proof* (sketch): Fix $\eps > 0$ arbitrarily. Use summability of $(c_{n})$ to choose a natural number $N$ such that
$$
\sum_{n = N+1}^{\infty} c_{n} < \eps.
$$
Now pick $\delta > 0$ so that $(x - \delta, x + \delta)$ contains none of the $x_{n}$ with $n \leq N$; for example, take
$$
\delta = \min \{|x_{n} - x| : 1 \leq n \leq N\}.
$$
If $|x - y| < \delta$, then
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} c_{n} < \eps.
$$
(The first inequality requires justification; the point is, each of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ is a sum of various $c_{n}$, but if $n \leq N$, then $x_{n}$ does not lie between $x$ and $y$, so "$c_{n}$ does not appear in the difference".)

This lemma handles part (c). Part (b) is immediate from the following "trick": For each $n$, we can "decompose" $f$ as
$$
f(x) = \underbrace{f(x) - f_{n}(x)}_{g_{n}(x)} + f_{n}(x).
$$
The difference $g_{n}(x)$ on the right-hand side is precisely the function constructed in the same manner as $f$, except by eliminating the point $x_{n}$ from the set $E$, and removing the corresponding summand from $f(x)$. As such $g_{n}$ is continuous at $x_{n}$ by the lemma (!). Since $f_{n}$ has a jump discontinuity at $x_{n}$, $f$ does, as well.

Comment: D.Hwang, can you explain your last paragraph about $g_n(x)$? Sorry but I can't understand it since English not my native.

Comment: @Pacman: The idea is that the jump in $f(x)$ is "entirely caused by" the term $f_{n}$, so "removing" (i.e., subtracting) that term leaves a continuous function, $g_{n}$. More rigorously, removing one term from an infinite sequence (here, the discontinuities of $f$) leaves an infinite sequence (the discontinuities of $g_{n}$). By the lemma, $g_{n}$ is continuous at $x_{n}$, so $f = g_{n} + f_{n}$ must be discontinuous at $x_{n}$.

Comment: D.Hwang, why $g_n$ is continuous at $x_n\in E$ by lemma? Lemma is about that $f(x)$ is continuous at every point of $(a,b)\setminus E$

Comment: The lemma says the sum of a sequence of a certain family of step functions is continuous at each point that is not a discontinuity of a term of the sequence. As you say, $f$ is a function of this type, but $g_{n}$ is also such a function. If you like, the "$f$" in the statement of the lemma refers to a _generic_ sum of step functions, not (merely) to the function $f$ in the problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : Note that, $\forall x\in (x_n,x_{n+1}]$, for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i$$ which shows that $f$ is increasing in $(a,b)$ and also, $f(x_n+)-f(x_n-)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} c_i=c_n$ Also, note that the function is left continuous.

It is better to first draw the function in your mind and then go for the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, which would easily follow from the picture.

Comment: But this is only an intuitive argument; it's not a rigorous proof.

Comment: Yes, I have not given you the rigorous proof, but I have shown you how to think one.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay, I upvoted you about a year ago, but now I realize that things can't always be made so simple as $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i$. What if we want discontinuity at *every* rational in $(a,b)$? Then $f(x)$ is an infinite series for every $x$.

Comment: @Silent, that's a good point. In that case, though, we can write, $f(x_n-)$ as the sum of $c_n$'s which is a subsequence of the sequence $c_n$ that, when summed, produce $f(x_n+)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think this example begs for the use of the concept of 
an absolutely summable family, as defined by Dieudonne in
Chapter V, Section 3 of *Foundations of Modern Analysis*,
or (at an introductory undergraduate level) in Chapter 5 of
Alan F. Beardon, *Limits: A New Approach to Real Analysis*.

(Of course one can do without this, and perhaps then it is
best to ignore Rudin's remark that "the order in which the
terms are arranged is immaterial," which may be a bit of
a red herring, because instead of using absolutely summable
families one can define the sum of any series $\sum c_{n_k}$,
where $( n_k : k \in \mathbb{N} )$ is any strictly increasing
sequence, and then of course the order of the terms remains
the same.)

If $J = \{ 1, 2, 3, \dotsc \}$, then $( c_n : n 
\in J \}$ is an absolutely summable family, therefore so 
is $( c_n : n \in J_x )$, where $J_x = \{ n \in 
J : x_n < x \}$, for all $x \in (a, b)$, and:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n \in J_x} c_n \qquad (a < x < b).
$$

The ordering of the index set $J$ is not used, and $( x_n
: n \in J )$ may be just any countable family in
$(a, b)$.  It is injective, but I don't think we need this.
However, for neatness, we 
can exploit the unused injectivity, as follows:

Take the given countable subset $E \subset (a, b)$ as the 
index set for the absolutely summable family, which now 
becomes $( c_x : x \in E )$.

If possible, I won't use the assumption that $E$ is infinite,
i.e. $E$ is *at most* countable.

Define:
\begin{gather*}
\mu(S) = \sum_{y \in S} c_y \qquad (S \subseteq E), \\
f(x) = \mu(E \cap (a, x)) \qquad (a < x < b).
\end{gather*}

Property (a) is trivial.

To prove (b) and (c) together, we need to prove: (i)
$f(x-) = f(x)$; (ii) $f(x+) = \mu(E \cap (a, x])$.

**Proof of (i).**

For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists finite 
$F \subset E \cap (a, x)$ such that $\mu(F) > f(x) - \epsilon.$
If $\max(F) < t < x$, then $f(t) > f(x) - \epsilon$.  Since 
we already know that $f(x-) \leqslant f(x)$, this proves that
$f(x-) = f(x)$.

**Proof of (ii).**

Define $g(x) = \mu(E \cap (a, x])$ and $h(x) = \mu(E \cap (x, b))$.
Then $g(x) + h(x) = \mu(E)$, which is a constant
independent of $x$.  By the same argument as in (i) (or 
else by a change of variable from $x$ to $a + b - x$), we 
have $h(x+) = h(x)$, therefore $g(x+) = g(x)$.  But it is 
clear that $f(x+) = g(x+)$, because if $x < t < u < b,$
then $f(t) \leqslant g(u)$ and $g(t) \leqslant f(u)$.  Hence
$f(x+) = g(x)$. Q.E.D.

Comment: These notes are regurgitated from when I chewed over the same problem in 2004. I've only tidied up the notation, and added a reference to the textbook by Beardon. It's surprisingly hard to concentrate on a problem afresh when merely rehashing old notes like this - worth trying once, but perhaps not again!

Comment: This has been downvoted. Is the argument invalid, or just unclear? Either way, I'll work through it again, if I know what to look for - and simply delete it, if it's irreparably bad. (No rush - I can't attend to it immediately, anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $M\in\mathbb N$ so large that $\sum_{m=M+1}^\infty c_m<\varepsilon$.

Then choose $\delta>0$ so small that all points in $\{x_1,\ldots,x_M\}$ with the possible exception of $x$ itself, are at a distance $>\delta$ from $x$.

Probably you can take it from there.

**PS:** So if $|y-x|<\delta$, then $|f(y)-f(x)|$ is a sum of members of the sequence $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ whose sum is less than $\varepsilon$, unless $x$ itself is in the sequence.  That proves continuity at numbers $x$ that are not in the sequence.

Now suppose $x$ is in the sequence. Then $x= x_k$ for some $k$.  Then if $x<y<x+\delta$, then again $|f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for the same reason.  But in this case, we need to prove that $f(x-)$ would be the sum of all members of $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ for which $x_k<x$, and $f(x)=f(x+)$ would be that sum plus $c_k$.  So suppose $0<x-y<\delta$.
Then $f(y)$ differs from the sum of all members of $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ for which $x_k<x$ by a sum of members of $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ that is less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: if $x \not\in E$ and if $|y-x| < \delta$, then none of  $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ lies between $x$ and $y$. Then?

Comment: can you please complete your argument? I'm too dull, I'm afraid, to be able to take it from where you;ve left.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add an answer here to make (b) more explicit.
I would comment to improve upon tchappy's answer but I don't have enough reputation points.

To show $f(x+) - f(x-) = c_n$ for $x \in E$, we show the following from which the result follows by rearrangement.
$$\text{(I) }f(x-) = \sum_{x_n \lt x} c_n $$
$$\text{(II) }f(x+) = \sum_{x_n \leq x} c_n $$

From Theorem 4.29, we have
$$f(x-) = sup_{a<t<x}f(t) $$
$$f(x+) = inf_{x<t<b}f(t) $$

We first establish (I).
By monotonicity, for all $t<x$, $f(t)\leq f(x) = \sum_{x_n \lt x} c_n$.
So we have that $\sum_{x_n \lt x} c_n$ is an upperbound of $\{f(t) | a<t<x \}$. We show it is a least upperbound.

For arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, we have a positive integer $N$ such that
$$ \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} c_n < \epsilon $$

We have two sequences as follows:
$\{x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_N, ...\}$
$\{c_1, c_2, c_3, ..., c_N, ...\}$
We wish to determine some $t$ where $a<t<x$ so that
$$f(x) - f(t) = \sum_{x_n \lt x} c_n - \sum_{x_n \lt t} c_n = \sum_{t \leq x_n \lt x} c_n < \epsilon$$

By producing a $t$ such that $a<t<x$ for which no element of $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N\}$  satisfies $t \leq x_n \lt x$, we can conclude that

$$ f(x) - f(t) = \sum_{t \leq x_n \lt x} c_n \leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} c_n < \epsilon $$
So we proceed to produce such a $t$.
If $x\leq\text{min}(x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)$, then the series $f(x)$ already contains no element of $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N\}$ and for any $a<t<b$:

$$f(x)- f(t) \leq f(x) \leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} c_n < \epsilon$$

Otherwise, there exists some $x_i \in \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N\}$ such that $x_i \lt x$. We choose maximal such $x_i$ and let $t = \frac{x + x_i}{2}$. Then by choice of $t$, no $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N\}$ satisfies $t \leq x_n \lt x$.

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude that (I) holds.

The proof for (II) follows similarly.
We establish $\sum_{x_n \leq x} c_n$ to be a lowerbound of $\{f(t) | x<t<b \}$ by noting that for any $t$ such that $x<t<b$, $$f(t)= \sum_{x_n \lt t} c_n \geq \sum_{x_n \leq x} c_n$$

And similarly, for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ we produce $t$ where $x<t<b$ such that $$f(t) - \sum_{x_n \leq x} c_n = \sum_{x \lt x_n \lt t} c_n < \epsilon$$

by disinguishing two cases; $x\geq\text{max}(x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)$ and otherwise. The first case is again trivial, while in the second case, we observe that there exists some $x_i \in \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N\}$ such that $x_i \gt x$. We choose minimal such $x_i$ as $t$, so we have no element of $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N\}$ that satisfies $x \lt x_n \lt t$ and the statement (II) follows.

Answer (score 0):

1. $\sup_{a<t<x_n} f(t) = \sum_{x_i<x_n} c_i$.
2. $\inf_{x_n<t<b} f(t) = \sum_{x_i\leq x_n} c_i$.

Proof of 1.:
If $a < t < x_n$, then $f(t) \leq f(x_n)$ since $f$ is monotonically increasing on $(a, b)$.
Let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.
Let $N$ be a natural number such that $$\sum_{i = N}^{\infty} c_i < \epsilon.$$
There exists $t_0$ such that $a < t_0 < x_n$ and $N \leq \min \{i | t_0 \leq x_i < x_n\}$ ($\min \emptyset = +\infty$).
$$f(x_n) - f(t_0) = \sum_{i \in \{i | t_0 \leq x_i < x_n\}} c_i \leq \sum_{i = N}^{\infty} c_i < \epsilon.$$
So, $$f(x_n) - \epsilon < f(t_0) \leq f(x_n).$$
So, $$\sup_{a<t<x_n} f(t) = f(x_n-) = f(x_n) = \sum_{x_i<x_n} c_i.$$

Proof of 2.:
If $x_n < t < b$, then $\sum_{x_i\leq x_n} c_i \leq \sum_{x_i < t} c_i = f(t)$.
Let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.
Let $N$ be a natural number such that $$\sum_{i = N}^{\infty} c_i < \epsilon.$$
There exists $t_0$ such that $x_n < t_0 < b$ and $N \leq \min \{i | x_n < x_i < t_0\}$($\min \emptyset = +\infty$).
$$f(t_0) - \sum_{x_i \leq x_n} c_i = \sum_{x_i < t_0} c_i - \sum_{x_i \leq x_n} c_i = \sum_{x_n < x_i < t_0} c_i \leq \sum_{i = N}^{\infty} c_i < \epsilon.$$
So, $$\sum_{x_i \leq x_n} c_i \leq f(t_0) < \sum_{x_i \leq x_n} c_i + \epsilon.$$
So, $$\inf_{x_n<t<b} f(t) = f(x_n+) = f(x_n) + c_n = \sum_{x_i\leq x_n} c_i.$$

From the above proof of 1. and 2., $f(x_n+) - f(x_n-) = c_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt that uses what Rudin has established up to chapter 4.

Fix $a<x<b$ and $\epsilon>0$. Let $\Lambda$ be the set of all $j$'s such
that $x_j<x$. If $\Lambda$ is finite, then we can find a $p$ for which
$x_j<p<x$ for all $j\in\Lambda$, whence for $p<\xi<x$, $f(\xi)=f(x)$.
Otherwise, we can arrange $\Lambda$ in a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$. Since
$f(x)=\sum c_{\alpha_n}$, there is an $N$ such that
$$n\geq N\qquad\mbox{implies}\qquad f(x)-\epsilon<\sum^n_{j=1}c_{\alpha_j}\leq
  f(x)\mbox{.}$$
Choose $p'<x$ so that $p'>x_{\alpha_j}$, $j=1,2,...,N$. It follows that
$$|f(x)-f(\xi)|<\epsilon\qquad\mbox{whenever}\qquad p'<\xi<x\mbox{.}$$
This shows that $f(x-)=f(x)$.

Next, we prove that $f(x_n+)=c_n+f(x_n); f(x+)=f(x), x\not=x_n$. Observe that
for $x'>x$,
$$\begin{align*}
  f(x') &= f(x)+\sum_{x\leq x_j<x'}c_j \\
        &= \begin{array}{ll}
             f(x)+c_n+\sum_{x<x_j<x'} & \mbox{if }x=x_n\mbox{ for some }n \\
             f(x)+\sum_{x<x_j<x'} & \mbox{otherwise}
           \end{array}\mbox{,}
\end{align*}$$
therefore it suffices to show that $\sum_{x<x_j<x'}$ can be made arbitrarily
small if only $x'$ is close enough to $x$ from the right. By Cauchy
criterion, there exists $M$ such that
$$ \sum_{j=m}^nc_j < \epsilon\qquad\mbox{for }n\geq m\geq M\mbox{.}$$
Picking $q>x$ so that $(x,q)$ contains no points $x_1,x_2,...,x_M$, we thus
have
$$\sum_{x<x_j<q}c_j\leq\epsilon\mbox{.}$$
This establishes (b) and (c).