# Does $f(x_n^+)=\inf\limits_{x_n<t< b}f(t)=\sum\limits_{x_i\leq x_n}c_i$ hold? Remark 4.31 in "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

Let $E$ be a countable subset of $(a, b)$.
Let $\phi$ be a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $E$.
Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence such that $x_n := \phi(n)$.
Let $\{c_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\sum c_n$ converges.
Let $f(x)$ be a function on $(a, b)$ defined by $f(x) := \sum\limits_{x_n < x} c_n$.
***Does the following equality hold?***:
$$f(x_n^+) = \inf_{x_n < t < b} f(t) = \sum_{x_i \leq x_n} c_i.$$

I am not sure that the above equality holds or not.

My attempt is here:

Since
$$\{i | x_i < x_n\} \cup \{n\} = \{i | x_i \leq x_n\},$$
$$f(x_n) + c_n = \sum_{i \in \{i | x_i < x_n\}} c_i + \sum_{i \in \{n\}} c_i = \sum_{i \in \{i | x_i < x_n\} \cup \{n\}} c_i = \sum_{\{i | x_i \leq x_n\}} c_i = \sum_{x_i \leq x_n} c_i.$$

If $t > x_n$, $$f(x_n) + c_n \leq f(t),$$ since $$n \not \in \{i | x_i < x_n\} \subsetneqq \{i | x_i < t\} \ni n.$$

Comment: Your attempt proves that $\inf\,\ldots \leq \sum\ldots$. You must also prove that for any real number $r > f(x_n)+c_n$, there exists $t>x_n$ such that $f(t) \leq r$.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mindlack. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3113870/384082